# jquery ui connect 2 tables, one sortable, one only draggable (as source)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have 2 tables, 
the left one is empty and should be sortable,
the right one serves as source and should not be sortable, I want these entries always to be sorted alphanumeric.

The function should now be: to move items from the source table into the empty table (then they disappear from the source table), and sort them in the 'empty' table.

And to move items back in the source table if you don't need them anymore, so they again appear in the source table, but the source table always is sorted alphanumeric.

My best try so far is to use the connectWith option as I can move items between both tables, but how can I prevent the source table to be sortable?

**Edit:**
I could come closer to what I need, but there's a problem I found no solution.

So far I can sort list 1,
I can move draggable items from list2 into list1 and sort them, and they disappear in list 2,
I can move items from list1 over list2 and drop them, and they disappaer from list1.

But if I hover with a draggable-item from list2 over list1 and let it drop back to list2 (maybe taken a wrong item or whatever), and then moving a sortable-item in list1 (even to its same place), then this removes that draggable-item from its list2, although it is not 'received' by the sortable list1.

So how can I prevent this? Only items wich are dropped into the sortable list1 should be removed from the draggable list2.

http://jsbin.com/yafakuje/14/edit

HTML:

```
<h2>#sortable</h2>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="no_1" class="ui-state-default da">Item 1</li>
  <li id="no_2" class="ui-state-default da">Item 2</li>
  <li id="no_3" class="ui-state-default da">Item 3</li>
  <li id="no_4" class="ui-state-default da">Item 4</li>
  <li id="no_5" class="ui-state-default da">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<h2>#draggable</h2>
<ul id="draggable">
  <li id="no_6" class="ui-state-default dr">Item 6</li>
  <li id="no_7" class="ui-state-default dr">Item 7</li>
  <li id="no_8" class="ui-state-default dr">Item 8</li>
  <li id="no_9" class="ui-state-default dr">Item 9</li>
  <li id="no_10" class="ui-state-default dr">Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
  receive: function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.item).remove();
    },
  over: function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.helper).css('cursor',"move");
    },
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.item).css('cursor','auto');
    },
  out: function( event, ui ){
    $(ui.helper).css('cursor','no-drop');
    },
  update: function () {
    var order = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize');
    //order later on send to the server via jquery-ajax $post
    alert(order);
  } 
}).disableSelection();


$( ".dr" ).draggable({
  connectToSortable: "#sortable",
  helper: "clone",
  start: function( event, ui ){
    $(ui.helper).css('cursor','no-drop');  
  }
}).disableSelection();


$( "#draggable" ).droppable({ 
  accept: ".da",
  drop: function(event,ui) {
    $(ui.draggable).remove();
    },
  over: function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.helper).css('cursor',"alias");
    },
  out: function( event, ui ){
    $(ui.helper).css('cursor','no-drop');  
    }
});
```

Edit2:

For those of you hobby-programmers which like to have some working code instead of a hard readable syntax, here's some of my code. It's one kind of solution, there may be other and better ways, but it works for me.

The code calls a popup, and in that popup is the sortable and draggable list. Each time something is moved or dragged I refresh to popup completely, therefore all the popup code is in my ajax.php and it calls itself recursively.
The popup is called from a table field, sure there are more than one row, each with its own id to call the right data into the popup.

php/html with the table and the popup template

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr dataID="'.$row['id'].'">
        <td></td>
        <td class="call_popup"> some data </td>';
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div id="popup">
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="popup">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS (to call the popup)

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception){
        alert("An error occurred! Unable to get/set data!\nError: "+exception);
    });

    $(".call_popup").click(function() {
        var ID = $(this).parent("tr").attr('dataID');
        $.post("ajax.php",{action:'getpopup',id:ID},
            function(popup_content){
                $("#popup").children("div.popup").html(popup_content);

                $("#content").css("overflow","hidden");
                $("#popup").children(".popup").fadeIn(700);
                $("#popup").children(".background").css("opacity", "0.7");
                $("#popup").children(".background").fadeIn(700);
            }
        );
    });

    $(".background").click(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(600);
            $(".popup").fadeOut(600);
            $("#content").css("overflow","auto");
    });

});
```

ajax.php which gets/sets data from/to the server and creates the popup with sortable/draggable list

```
<?php

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']=='admin')
{
    require_once("sql_database.php");

    $action =  $_POST['action'];
    $data   = @$_POST['data'];
    $id     =  $_POST['id'];

    if ($action=='setsomething') {
        //some code
    } elseif ($action=='setothersomething') {
        //some code
    } elseif ($action=='setpopup') {
            parse_str($data,$part_data);

            mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE id = '$id'") or die(header('HTTP/1.1 503'));

            $i=0;
            if (!empty($part_data)) {
                foreach($part_data['no'] as $part_data_id ) {
                    $i++;
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table SET
                                id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."',
                                sequence = '$i',
                                data_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($part_data_id)."'
                                ") or die(header('HTTP/1.1 503'));
                }
            }
    } elseif ($action=='getsomething') {
        //some code
    } elseif ($action=='getothersomething') {
        //some code
    } elseif ($action=='getpopup') {
            $result_sortable = mysql_query("SELECT data_id,data_name FROM table
                                    WHERE id = $id
                                    ORDER BY sequence ") or die(header('HTTP/1.1 503'));
            $result_draggable = mysql_query("SELECT data_id,data_name FROM table
                                    ") or die(header('HTTP/1.1 503'));

            header('HTTP/1.1 200 server');
            echo '
            <div id="left">
                <ol id="sortable">';
                    while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_sortable)) {
                        echo '
                        <li pos="no_'.$data['data_id'].'" class="da">'.$data['data_name'].'</li>
                        ';
                    }
            echo '
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <ul id="draggable">';
                while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_draggable)) {
                    echo '
                        <li pos="no_'.$data['data_id'].'" class="dr">'.$data['data_name'].'</li>
                        ';
                }
                echo  '</ul>
            </div>';

            echo '
            <script>
                $("#sortable").sortable({
                    receive: function(event,ui) {
                        //$(ui.item).remove();
                        },
                    over: function(event,ui) {
                        $(ui.helper).css("cursor","move");
                        },
                    stop: function(event,ui) {
                        $(ui.item).css("cursor","auto");
                        },
                    out: function(event,ui) {
                        $(ui.helper).css("cursor","no-drop");
                        },
                    update: function() {
                        var order = $("#sortable").sortable("serialize",{attribute:"pos"});
                        var scrollPosition = $("#right").scrollTop();
                        $.post("ajax.php",{action:"setpopup",data:order,id:'.$id.'},
                            function() {
                                $.post("ajax.php",{action:"getpopup",id:'.$id.'},
                                    function(popup_content){
                                        $("#popup").children("div.popup").html(popup_content);
                                        $("#right").scrollTop(scrollPosition);
                                    }
                                );
                            }
                        );
                        }
                }).disableSelection();

                $(".dr").draggable({
                        connectToSortable: "#sortable",
                        helper: "clone",
                    start: function(event,ui){
                        $(ui.helper).css("cursor","no-drop");  
                        }
                }).disableSelection();

                $("#draggable").droppable({ 
                        accept: ".da",
                    drop: function(event,ui) {
                        $(ui.draggable).remove();
                        },
                    over: function(event,ui) {
                        $(ui.helper).css("cursor","alias");
                        },
                    out: function(event,ui) {
                        $(ui.helper).css("cursor","no-drop");  
                        }
                });

            </script>';
            die;
    }

    header('HTTP/1.1 200 server');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $array = array('success' => true);
    echo json_encode($array);


} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 401');//Unauthorized
}


?>
```